# html file doesn't apply css file but works in online compiler

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I was following [this guy's guide](http://www.littlewebhut.com/html5/css_layout/) to learn HTML and CSS, and realized my CSS didn't apply. So I copied his codes and replaced my codes and the CSS still didn't apply, just the HTML (I put them under the same dir and I had tried different browsers like google crome, ie and Microsoft page, none of them worked), but when I put the codes on an online compiler, the result is exactly the same as in the tutorial video.

Can anyone explain to me what caused the problem and how to fix it?

Here is the link to his codes: [Little WebHut](http://www.littlewebhut.com/html5/css_layout/).

Comment: hello and welcome. could you post your code so people could have a look and see whats going on? it would be helpful to see your file structure too.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard the see whats going on, but it looks like it could be a file structure problem.

the 'guys' code is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

but typically the CSS would be in a folder so the code to link the style sheet would be 'folderName/style.css' with the actural name of the folder replacing the words 'folderName'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folderName/style.css">
```

I would also try a hard refresh (on windows ctrl+r on your webpage) or delete browser cache.

Comment: I put both of the CSS and HTML files under the same folder so there shouldn't be a program unless I missed something in previous tutorials.

Comment: you'll need to post your code then so we can have a look at whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I made a mistake. I named my CSS file style.css so it became style.css.css.